# Plotting time-series plots and converting from 24-h to 12-h

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the number of PIT tagged animal detections on a antenna per hour. I have a nice plot that shows when animals are being detected, yet I want to scale the x-axis as a 12 hour instead of 24 hour.

```r
ggplot(merger1,aes(x=(hour(`Scan Time`)))) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Enconter Hour") +
  ggtitle('Encounter Timing by Hour') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Right now the x-axis goes from 0-24, ideally I would like it to go from 12 am on the left axis, to 12 pm in the middle of the plot, back to 12 am on the right axis so we can clearly see when detections are occuring throughout the day.

My Scan Time column is stored as "POSIXct" "POSIXt" and I cant use the scale_x_datetime function to format the time because it wont work with POSIXt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert 24h to AM/PM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510271/convert-24h-to-am-pm-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `lubridate::hour` (I'm inferring), your x-axis will be in integers, so no discussion about `format` on a `POSIXt` object is going to be applicable. I suggest you just modulus it.

Sample data,

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = Sys.time() + sample(86400, size=100))
ggplot(dat, aes(lubridate::hour(x))) + geom_bar()
```

*(Edit: I removed the `set.seed(.)`, since my use of `Sys.time()` made this not-reproducible unless you knew the time that I ran that command first. I don't, so if you do ... weird. :-)*

[image]

Fixed:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(lubridate::hour(x))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = function(z) (z-1) %% 12 + 1, 
    breaks = function(z) pretty(z, n = 12)
  )
```

[image]

If you want AM/PM appended, then try

```r
ampm <- function(hr) paste((hr-1) %% 12 + 1, ifelse(hr %% 24 < 12, "am", "pm"))
ggplot(dat, aes(lubridate::hour(x))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = ampm,
    breaks = function(z) pretty(z, n = 12)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly!! I am certainly no expert using r (I am not even sure what the z means in the above code) but luckily r2evans is a genius!!

Comment: The `z` is just a temporary variable, a function argument in an anonymous function. Usually, objects passed to function arguments are just data, as in vectors, lists, or frames. Occasionally, however, it's useful (necessary) to provide a function instead of data, so that when it comes time to determine what the breaks should be (for example), the anon-func gets two numbers (the outer extremes of the axis); the anon-func passed to `labels=` is given a vector of x-axis numbers, and determines how they should look. This is the standard of how to control axes in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
ggplot(merger1,aes(x=(hour(`Scan Time`)))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = ("%I %p"),
                   timezone = "GMT", 
                   date_breaks = "2 hours",
                   expand = c(0, 0))
  xlab("Enconter Hour") +
  ggtitle('Encounter Timing by Hour') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: This does not work, it gives me the same error as I was dealing with before... Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only. I used parse_date_time to format the Scan Time column orignally because I needed to get rid of milliseconds.   merger1$`Scan Time` <- parse_date_time(merger1$`Scan Time`,"%H:%M:%OS"). This got rid of milliseconds, but added a date to the time as well. I assume that because I am only trying to work with the time (stored as POSIXt) is why I am getting the error, but I dont know how to remedy the problem.